# Split lists according to number of words

Tags: r, list, split, count

I have 3 lists of character vectors as e.g.

```
list1 = list(c("bla bla bla bla", "sample text", "dumdidum bla bla", "a very long text is written in here"))
list2 = list(c("bla ", "blubb"))
list3 = list(c("bla bla bla bla", "sample text", "another very long text", "cat dog bird"))
```

and I would like to create a new list in the same format which only contains the entries of the above lists that count more than 3 words. The entries which will be placed in the new list should be deleted in the original lists. 
My desired output should be in this form:

```
list1 = list(c("sample text", "dumdidum bla bla"))
list2 = list(c("bla ", "blubb"))
list3 = list(c("sample text","cat dog bird"))

newlist = list(c("bla bla bla bla", "a very long text is written in here", "bla bla bla bla", "another very long text"))
```

Is there a possibility to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your data into a list and then used `lapply`:

```
data_list <- list(
    list1 = list(c("bla bla bla bla", "sample text", "dumdidum bla bla", "a very long text is written in here")),
    list2 = list(c("bla ", "blubb")),
    list3 = list(c("bla bla bla bla", "sample text", "another very long text", "cat dog bird")))

data_vec <- unname(unlist(data_list))

data_list <- lapply(data_list,function(x){
    keep_ind <- lapply(strsplit(x[[1]]," "),length) <= 3
    c(x[[1]][keep_ind])
})

newlist <- data_vec[!data_vec %in% unlist(data_list)]

data_list
#$list1
#[1] "sample text"      "dumdidum bla bla"
#
#$list2
#[1] "bla "  "blubb"
#
#$list3
#[1] "sample text"  "cat dog bird"

newlist
#[1] "bla bla bla bla"                     "a very long text is written in here"
#[3] "bla bla bla bla"                     "another very long text"
```

Comment: Thank you. Works really nicely. But I still need to remove the entries in the old lists..

Comment: I changed my solution accordingly, you now get the old lists as well the new list.

Comment: Thank you, but I need the opposite lists. So list1, list2, list3 should only contain the strings with less than 3 words.

Comment: I see, I missed that part in your question. I changed my solution again accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `stringi` library,

```
library(stringi)

v1 <- unlist(c(list1, list2, list3))
v2 <- v1[stri_count_words(v1) > 3]
v2

#[1] "bla bla bla bla" "a very long text is written in here" "bla bla bla bla"  "another very long text"
```

To remove those words from original lists, then,

```
lapply(c(list1, list2, list3), function(i) setdiff(i, v2))
```

which gives,

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "sample text"      "dumdidum bla bla"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "bla "  "blubb"
>
> [[3]]
> [1] "sample text"  "cat dog bird"
> ```

Comment: Unlisting from the beginning is very nice, it makes the solution very simple!

Comment: @tobiasegli_te Thanks. I thought that since the OP does not want to differentiate from which list the words came from, then unlisting it seemed the easy route

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
list(unlist(lapply(c(list1, list2, list3), function(x) x[str_count(x, "\\w+")>3])))
#[[1]]
#[1] "bla bla bla bla"                     "a very long text is written in here" "bla bla bla bla"                     "another very long text"
```